# How to remove a specific line of a text file based on the line number?

Tags: vbscript

I wondered if anybody could help me. I'm trying to amend the below script so it removes a specific line within a text file.  I'm baffled as to what part i need to amend below so it removes the exact line I want.

```
Const FOR_READING = 1 
Const FOR_WRITING = 2 
strFileName = "\\jarvisfs1\groups\InforIFC\Licence_BOB\NEW\test3.txt" 
iNumberOfLinesToDelete = 5 

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_READING) 
strContents = objTS.ReadAll 
objTS.Close 

arrLines = Split(strContents, vbNewLine) 
Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_WRITING) 

For i= 0 To UBound(arrLines) 
   If ShouldSkip(i) Then 
      objTS.WriteLine arrLines(i) 
   End If 
Next 

Function ShouldSkip(i)
    Dim arrSkipLines, x
    arrSkipLines = Array(1, 22, 32, 42, 169)
    For Each x In arrSkipLines
        If x = i Then
            ShouldSkip = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    ShouldSkip = False
End Function
```

Comment: What's wrong? What doesn't work? Any error message?

Comment: `If not ShouldSkip(i) Then` ? Looks like you are saving the lines that should be skip

Comment: Apologies my lack of knowledge of scripting, i've taken another script to modify to do what I want. I've just realized the array part is saving the lines, and actually want to remove a specific line. Is there anyway of changing the script so it removes the one line I want removing?

Comment: Check my comment again, use `not` to reverse the condition

Comment: Need to use the eyes i was blessed with ;).. Thanks cid this works a charm (well once I realized I was opening the test file to quick for the script to finishing working lol)..

Comment: Hi, how do I delete the blank lines which are being created.